# Number of faces of $n$ congruent disks

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-geometry

If I have $n$ disks, all of the same radius, how many faces (i.e. maximally connected regions) can the induced arrangement have? For example for 3 disks, it could have 7 bounded faces, but  what is the asymptotic dependence on $n$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Viewing the disks as circles, if each one intersects each of the others, you get a graph with $n(n-1)$ vertices, all of degree $4$, so $2n(n-1)$ edges, so, by $v-e+f=1$, $n(n-1)+1$ faces.

That would be an upper bound, as I'm not certain it can be arranged that each pair of disks has an overlap.

Comment: Oh good idea. 
And yes your bound is asymptotically tight, because placing n unit disk on a line, with a gap of 1/n, indeed lets every two disks intersect